# Linux Scheduling Mechanism in 2.6.22?

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduler

I'm doing some kind of performance evaluation using two different vanilla Linux kernels, `2.6.22` and `2.6.31`, since I assume each of them uses a different scheduling mechanism: `2.6.22` uses the old *O(1)* scheduler, whilst `2.6.31` adopts the *CFS*. Could anybody confirm the correction of this assumption?

Answer (score 0):

It is in linux-2.6.23 introduced the CFS ( http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_2_6_23#head-f3a847a5aace97932f838027c93121321a6499e7 ) But the later kernel would have patches for it. IMHO, you could try a newer kernel if you want to do profiling.